# How to filter columns containing missing values

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the following code:

```
sns.displot(
    data=df.isna().melt(value_name="missing"),
    y="variable",
    hue="missing",
    multiple="fill",
    height=16
)
plt.show()
```

to create a heatmap of missing values of the `df`. However since my `df` has a lot of columns, the chart has to be very tall in order to accommodate all the information. I tried altering the `data` argument to be something like this:

`data = df[df.columns.values.isna()].isna()` or `data = df[df.isna().sum() > 0].isna()` so basically, I want to filter the dataframe to have only columns with at least one missing value. I tried looking for a correct answer but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nearly there. To select all columns with at least one missing value, use:

```
df[df.columns[df.isna().any()]]
```

Alternatively, you could use `.sum()` and then choose some threshold:

```
threshold = 0
df[df.columns[df.isna().sum() > threshold]]
```

And then append `.isna().melt(value_name="missing")` for your `data` var.

Comment: Is it possible to order the bars in the distplot by the number of missing values? I know there's an `order` argument.

Comment: .sort_values() after the melt ?

Comment: Not sure about `order` arg, but I would just sort the data beforehand. E.g. `data = df[df.columns[df.isna().any()]].isna()`, then `ordered_cols = data.sum().sort_values(ascending=True).index` (set to `False` for descending), finally `data = data[ordered_cols]`. Write all this before `sns.displot()` and then inside use `data=data.melt(value_name="missing")`.

Comment: Thanks! Believe I was missing `.index` in `data.sum().sort_values(ascending=True).index`.